# how to specify npm package.json with main folder nor main file

Tags: npm, package.json

I am creating a **npm package 1** that includes another **npm package 2**. The package 2 contains only some compiled html files, no js files in the folder `dist`. There is no main file. The package is supposed to be used only as a kind of archive.

What should I specify in the package.json? Should I specify `files: ["dist/"]`, or `main:'dist'`?

How can I access the folder `dist` from the package 1 that requires the package 2? `require('package2').dist`? or just `require('package2')`? I want to access the folder dist, so I can copy to some other location based on business logic of the package 1.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In npm/Node.js, `require()` only works on JavaScript files. So, you'll need to include some js in your package 2 to make things work.

Here's one idea - in package 2, create a `index.js` like so:

```
var path = require('path');

exports.base_path = path.join(__dirname, 'dist');
```

In your package.json, point `main` at this file.

Then in your package 1, you can easily and reliably get the base path to the html files:

```
var html_base_path = require('package2').base_path;
```

After that, you can use [read](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options) and [write](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createwritestream_path_options) streams to copy things around. For example, to copy package 2's `dist/index.html` to `/some/other/dir`, you could do:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

var html_base_path = require('package2').base_path;

var filename = 'index.html');
var sourcePath = path.join(html_base_path, filename);
var destPath = path.join('/some/other/dir', filename);
fs.createReadStream(sourcePath).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(destPath));
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation